# counting the occurrence of substrings in a column in R with group by

Tags: r, summarize

I would like to count the occurrences of a string  in a column ....per group. In this case the string is often a substring in a character column.

I have some data e.g.

```
ID   String              village
1    fd_sec, ht_rm,      A
2    NA, ht_rm           A
3    fd_sec,             B
4    san, ht_rm,         C
```

The code that I began with is obviously incorrect, but I am failing on my search to find out I could use the grep function in a column and group by village

```
impacts <- se %>%  group_by(village) %>%
summarise(c_NA = round(sum(sub$en41_1 ==  "NA")),
          c_ht_rm = round(sum(sub$en41_1 ==  "ht_rm")),
          c_san = round(sum(sub$en41_1 ==  "san")),
          c_fd_sec = round(sum(sub$en41_1 ==  "fd_sec")))
```

Ideally my output would be:

```
village  fd_sec  NA  ht_rm  san
A        1       1   2 
B        1
C                    1      1
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Split the "String" column and tabulate. You should post some [reproducible data first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: I would summarize using something like `c_ht_rm = length(grep("ht_rm", String))` for each of the substrings

Comment: sorry - thanks - re. reproducible data - I will do so in the future.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `cSplit()` from my "splitstackshape" package. Since this package also loads "data.table", you can then just use `dcast()` to tabulate the result.

Example:

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(mydf, "String", direction = "long")[, dcast(.SD, village ~ String)]
# Using 'village' as value column. Use 'value.var' to override
# Aggregate function missing, defaulting to 'length'
#    village fd_sec ht_rm san NA
# 1:       A      1     2   0  1
# 2:       B      1     0   0  0
# 3:       C      0     1   1  0
```

Answer (score 4):

We can do this with `base R` by `split`ting the 'String' column with 'village', then split the 'String' into substrings by splitting at `,` followed by zero or more spaces (`\\s*`), `stack` the `list` into a two column `data.frame` and get the frequency with `table`

```
table(stack(lapply(split(df1$String, df1$village), 
            function(x) unlist(strsplit(x, ",\\s*"))))[2:1])
#  values
#ind fd_sec ht_rm NA san   
#  A      1     2  1   0
#  B      1     0  0   0
#  C      0     1  0   1
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`, after grouping by 'village', reshape into 'long' format by splitting the 'String' using `separate_rows`, `filter` out the rows that have blank values in 'String', `count` the frequency and `spread` it to 'wide' format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(village) %>% 
   separate_rows(String, sep=",\\s*") %>%
   filter(nzchar(String)) %>% 
   count(village, String) %>% 
   spread(String, n, fill = 0)
# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups: village [3]
#  village fd_sec ht_rm  `NA`   san
#* <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 A         1.00  2.00  1.00  0   
#2 B         1.00  0     0     0   
#3 C         0     1.00  0     1.00
```

Comment: I'm getting `Error in strsplit(x, ",\\s*") : non-character argument` from your base R version.

Comment: @jaySf  `strsplit` takes `character` columns.  If it is `factor` do `strsplit(as.character(x), ",\\s*")`